# PHP get function is empty for hidden container

Tags: php, html

I am trying to $_GET a hidden input using PHP.

When I check the html code in Chrome, Safari, etc., I can see the value of the hidden variable but when I try to echo it with PHP it is empty. All of this is inside a modal.

I don't really understand what I am doing wrong.

I hope some of you can help me.

```
<form method="get">
<input name="hiddencontainer" type="hidden" id="hiddencontainer" value="default"/>
</form>


<div id="frame" class="modal">

  <div class="modal-content">

    <!-- Body content -->
    <div class="modal-body">

      <p id="content">
      <?php

        // Get information
        $id = $_GET["hiddencontainer"];
        echo $id;
      ?>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The hiddencontainer value will not show until after the form has been submitted to the page where you are trying to show it. When do you expect to see it? When the user fills it?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to modify the hidden container with javascript and then get the value in PHP. Can the form be submitted automatically?

Comment: Sure. Use AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to submit the form to get the value, try this

```html
<form method="get">
<input name="hiddencontainer" type="hidden" id="hiddencontainer" value="default"/>
Click the button to submit the form and you will see the value
<input type="submit" name="Submit form"/>
</form>


<div id="frame" class="modal">

  <div class="modal-content">

    <!-- Body content -->
    <div class="modal-body">

      <p id="content">
      <?php

        // Get information
        $id = $_GET["hiddencontainer"];
        echo $id;
      ?>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Rikard, thank you very much for your answer! This does work! But is it possible to submit the form through a javascript? something like: <script> var myhidden = document.getElementById("hiddencontainer"); myhidden.submit(); </script>

Comment: Yes, you can simulate sending the form `document.formName.submit()`. You need to set name of the form.